# Exchange Server 2016 Update: Database Mount Error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I was trying to upgrade my Exchange Server 2016 CU 20 to Exchange Server 2016 CU23 and on the
Step 7 of 11: Mailbox role: Mailbox service.
The upgrade is failing with the below error.

We repaired the affected database also, and the repair was successful.
Still seeing the error, nonetheless.

We tried to reboot the server, and that also did not fix the issue.

The database in question, is in a healthy state.

```
Error:
    The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 

          $name = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxUniqueName;
          $dispname = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxDisplayName;
          $dismbx = get-mailbox -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -resultSize 1;
          if( $dismbx -ne $null)
          {
          $srvname = $dismbx.ServerName;
          if( $dismbx.Database -ne $null -and $RoleFqdnOrName -like "$srvname.*" )
          {
          Write-ExchangeSetupLog -info "Setup DiscoverySearchMailbox Permission.";
          $mountedMdb = get-mailboxdatabase $dismbx.Database -status | where { $_.Mounted -eq $true };
          if( $mountedMdb -eq $null )
          {
          Write-ExchangeSetupLog -info "Mounting database before stamp DiscoverySearchMailbox Permission...";
          mount-database $dismbx.Database;
          }

          $mountedMdb = get-mailboxdatabase $dismbx.Database -status | where { $_.Mounted -eq $true };
          if( $mountedMdb -ne $null )
          {
          $dmRoleGroupGuid = [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.RoleGroup]::DiscoveryManagement_InitInfo.WellKnownGuid;
          $dmRoleGroup = Get-RoleGroup -Identity $dmRoleGroupGuid -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue;
          if( $dmRoleGroup -ne $null )
          {
            trap [Exception]
            {
              Add-MailboxPermission $dismbx -User $dmRoleGroup.Name -AccessRights FullAccess -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
              continue;
            }
            
            Add-MailboxPermission $dismbx -User $dmRoleGroup.Identity -AccessRights FullAccess -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue;
          }
          }
          }
          }
        " was run: "System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to mount database "env3-ex16-AdminDB". Error: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: The database action failed. Error: Operation failed with message: MapiExceptionDatabaseError: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 65256  
    Lid: 10722   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
    Lid: 1238    Remote Context Overflow
    Lid: 34760   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFDF0
    Lid: 41344   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 35200   dwParam: 0x1700
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034686 Msg: JI20
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT05
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT08
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM19
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM20
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM21
    Lid: 54472   StoreEc: 0x980     
    Lid: 42184   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 10786   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: 15.01.2507.006:ENV3-EX16:fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 51578   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
    Lid: 1047    StoreEc: 0x454      [Database: env3-ex16-AdminDB, Server: ENV3-EX16.sptestindia.com] ---> Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Replay.AmDbActionWrapperException: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: The database action failed. Error: Operation failed with message: MapiExceptionDatabaseError: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 65256  
    Lid: 10722   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
    Lid: 1238    Remote Context Overflow
    Lid: 34760   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFDF0
    Lid: 41344   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 35200   dwParam: 0x1700
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034686 Msg: JI20
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT05
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT08
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM19
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM20
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM21
    Lid: 54472   StoreEc: 0x980     
    Lid: 42184   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 10786   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: 15.01.2507.006:ENV3-EX16:fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 51578   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
    Lid: 1047    StoreEc: 0x454      [Database: env3-ex16-AdminDB, Server: ENV3-EX16.sptestindia.com] ---> Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.AmOperationFailedException: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: Operation failed with message: MapiExceptionDatabaseError: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 65256  
    Lid: 10722   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
    Lid: 1238    Remote Context Overflow
    Lid: 34760   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFDF0
    Lid: 41344   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 35200   dwParam: 0x1700
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034686 Msg: JI20
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT05
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT08
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM19
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM20
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM21
    Lid: 54472   StoreEc: 0x980     
    Lid: 42184   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 10786   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: 15.01.2507.006:ENV3-EX16:fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 51578   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
    Lid: 1047    StoreEc: 0x454      [Server: ENV3-EX16.sptestindia.com] ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionDatabaseError: MapiExceptionDatabaseError: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 65256  
    Lid: 10722   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
    Lid: 1238    Remote Context Overflow
    Lid: 34760   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFDF0
    Lid: 41344   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 35200   dwParam: 0x1700
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034686 Msg: JI20
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT05
    Lid: 43212   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: JT08
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM19
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM20
    Lid: 59596   dwParam: 0x2A034696 Msg: WM21
    Lid: 54472   StoreEc: 0x980     
    Lid: 42184   StoreEc: 0x454     
    Lid: 10786   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: 15.01.2507.006:ENV3-EX16:fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 51578   Guid: fb24818a-4b46-415b-bea4-6a2009cd595c
    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
    Lid: 1047    StoreEc: 0x454     
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.InternalThrowIfErrorOrWarning(String message, Int32 hresult, Boolean allowWarnings, Int32 ec, DiagnosticContext diagCtx, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, IExInterface iUnknown, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.ExRpcAdmin.MountDatabase(Guid guidStorageGroup, Guid guidMdb, Int32 ulFlags)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Replay.StoreRpcController.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<MountDatabase>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Shared.SafeRefCountedTimeoutWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<ProtectedCallWithTimeout>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.HA.InvokeWithTimeout.Invoke(Action invokableAction, Action foregroundAction, TimeSpan invokeTimeout, Boolean sendWatsonReportNoThrow, Object cancelEvent)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Shared.SafeRefCountedTimeoutWrapper.ProtectedCallWithTimeout(String operationName, TimeSpan timeout, Action operation)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmStoreHelper.Mount(Guid mdbGuid, MountFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.ActiveManagerCore.<>c__DisplayClass45_2.<MountDatabaseDirect>b__4()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Replay.FailoverPerformanceTrackerBase`1.RunTimedOperation(TOpCode opCode, Action operation)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.ActiveManagerCore.MountDatabaseDirect(Guid mdbGuid, MountFlags storeFlags, AmMountFlags amMountFlags, AmDbActionCode actionCode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmRpcServer.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<MountDatabaseDirect>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Cluster.HaRpcExceptionWrapperBase`2.RunRpcServerOperation(String databaseName, RpcServerOperation rpcOperation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Cluster.HaRpcExceptionWrapperBase`2.ClientRethrowIfFailed(String databaseName, String serverName, RpcErrorExceptionInfo errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ActiveManager.AmRpcClientHelper.RunRpcOperationWithAuth(AmRpcOperationHint rpcOperationHint, String serverName, String databaseName, NetworkCredential networkCredential, Nullable`1 timeoutMs, InternalRpcOperation rpcOperation)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ActiveManager.AmRpcClientHelper.MountDatabaseDirectEx(String serverToRpc, Guid dbGuid, AmMountArg mountArg)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmRpcClientWrapper.MountDatabaseDirectEx(String serverToRpc, Guid dbGuid, AmMountArg mountArg)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmDbAction.MountDatabaseDirect(AmServerName serverName, AmServerName lastMountedServerName, Guid dbGuid, MountFlags storeFlags, AmMountFlags amFlags, AmDbActionCode actionCode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmDbStandaloneAction.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<MountInternal>b__0(Object <p0>, EventArgs <p1>)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.ActiveManagerServer.AmHelper.HandleKnownExceptions(EventHandler ev)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Cluster.HaRpcExceptionWrapperBase`2.ClientRethrowIfFailed(String databaseName, String serverName, RpcErrorExceptionInfo errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ActiveManager.AmRpcClientHelper.RunDatabaseRpcWithReferral(AmRpcOperationHint rpcOperationHint, IADDatabase database, String targetServer, InternalRpcOperation rpcOperation)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.MountDatabase.RequestMount(MountFlags storeMountFlags)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.MountDatabase.InternalProcessRecord()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.ThrowError(Exception exception, ErrorCategory errorCategory, Object target, String helpUrl)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.WriteError(Exception exception, ErrorCategory category, Object target)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.MountDatabase.InternalProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.<ProcessRecord>b__91_1()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)".
```

Comment: Have you checked for network or other issues preventing the server from seeing the database, or rights to connect to it?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, the DB is on the server itself, and the server is not having any permission issue or access issue to the DB.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding Exchange server in maintenance mode?
Check [this guide](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/install-exchange-cumulative-updates.php).

The prerequisite for this update is Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 which you said is already installed.

You also need to [install a new Visual C++ component](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) - check [this changelog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/cumulative-update-23-for-exchange-server-2016-kb5011155-98183ada-e4cd-465f-b201-69d40fb74678).

You can apply this update when your database is repaired, the error that you have presented is because of corrupt database:

> unable to mount database (hr=0x80004005, ec=1108)

Because the error you have is of missing log files, Exchange Information Store is unable to start, not enough free disk space on database or log file volume, Exchange “Dirty Shutdown” error. You can use `Eseutil` command to repair corrupt database.